# Converting to Date (18 Jun 2006)

Tags: objective-c

I have this date that I'm getting from XML,

> 2009-11-05T02:15:03.000Z

How would I change it to

> 11 May 2009

I found a way to remove the .000Z so I only have this left

> 2009-11-05T02:15:03

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Google `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: And read the [excellent Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Along with the documentation for [date format strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).  Please try to avoid asking the same questions that others ask here daily, rather than reading and understanding the docs.

Comment: And understand that to do the above conversion you'd need to set a date formatter with the first format, convert from string to NSDate, then set a date formatter with the second format and convert back from NSDate to string.  Two different formats.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way would be to parse the original string to a date using an [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) configured with the format used to generate the date in XML, then use a second `NSDateFormatter` with the format style you want to use to format the parsed date.